# Python search and replace in a string

Tags: python

I have a variable defined in my python script called 'details' as shown below. I want to apply some regex on it and replace ${sub.name} which is between -n and -p with the name 'sam' and similarly want to replace ${sub.number} and ${sub.marks} with 7467 and 80.I want the output something like:-

```
-n sam -p 7467 -m 80
```

I am bit struggling to apply the regex even after alot of efforts. Any help? Thanks

Here is my code snippet:-

```
import re
details = "-n ${sub.name} -p ${sub.number} -m ${sub.marks}"
rep = re.sub(#apply regex)
```

Comment: Your code is full of holes such as parser not defined, StudenXML misspelled, `class` is a reserve word, Name not defined. Please go back and fix your own code, repost. Then you might get some help. Stackoverflow is in helping people find solution, not a code-writing-for-free service.

Comment: okay I have made the question easy to understand now @HaiVu

Comment: You can't expect anyone to help you, when the code your providing can not even be executed in the interpreter.

Comment: Check now @Perry.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution out of many. Python string formatting can replace those values, provide that

1. We remove the dollar signs from the `results` variable
2. We put all the substitutions into an instance of a class so that `{sub.name}` will become `sam`

Here is the code:

```
class Substitutions():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

sub = Substitutions(name='sam', number=7467, marks=80)
details = '-n ${sub.name} -p ${sub.number} -m ${sub.marks}'
details = details.replace('${', '{') # Remove all the dollar signs

result = details.format(sub=sub)
print result
```